# Single Page Section Scroll with Up and Down

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem with my code below in Firefox. It suppose to scroll sections up and down by clicking on elements with those classes. No errors and no visible problems just not scrolling. It is working fine in Chrome and Safari though. Can anybody suggest what's can cause the issue?

```
      $(function() {
        var $window = $(window);
        $('.arrow-icon-down').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.page-scroll').each(function() {
                var pos = $(this).offset().top;
                console.log('down');
                if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollTop: pos
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

        $('.arrow-icon-up').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $($('.page-scroll').get().reverse()).each(function() {
                var pos = $(this).offset().top;
                console.log('up');
                if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollTop: pos
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And the html structure is:

```
 <div class="page-scroll page-container clearfix hp-bkg" id="home">
   <div class="container fill-color"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-scroll page-container clearfix hp-bkg" id="overview">
   <div class="container fill-color"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-scroll page-container clearfix hp-bkg" id="contact">
   <div class="container fill-color"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid fixed-block hidden-xs">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 right">
     <a href="#" class="arrow-icon-up"></a>
     <a href="#" class="arrow-icon-down"></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Each of .page-scroll are having 100vh height.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to move the `event.preventDefault();` out of the each loop. This is assuming that you are trying to prevent the standard thing that happens on clicking an arrow.

Comment: I have done it but it didn't work I am afraid see my updated code above

Comment: Could you add the HTML too?

Comment: Just have done it. Thank you

Comment: The basic problem is that `$window.scrollTop()` is equal to 0 in Firefox so `$window.scrollTop() > pos` is always false (hence no scroll). Why that is though....

Comment: Thank you. Is there any possible way how to fix or workaround how to make it working?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this might help >> https://coderwall.com/p/b-zq7g/bugfix-jquery-animate-scrolling-for-firefox basically replace `$window` with `$('**html, body**')`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clue